# Nested array structures in C

Tags: structure

Below is the error that it is giving me and my code:

workspace.c: In function 'main':

workspace.c:38: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

workspace.c:39: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

any input would be greatly appreciated! and thank you for you time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define n 4
struct process
{
    struct segment{

        struct page
        {
            int pid;
            int p[4];
        }pages;
    }segments;
};

struct process processes[3];
struct page pages[n];
struct segment segments[n];

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    int k = 0;
     for(a = 0; a < 3; a++)
     {
            for(b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {
            for(c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                k++;
                processes[a].segments[b].pages[c].pid = k;
                printf("Segment: %d, Page: %d, PID: %d\n",a,b,processes[a].segments[b].pages[c].pid);
            }
        }

 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define`ing something as short as **n** is a bit dangerous, as it could lead to substitutions you didn't intend. `C` tradition is to use all upper case and something descriptive, such as `#define MAX_PAGES 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code : [Tested with no error](http://ideone.com/Fmki88)

```
#define n 4
struct process
{
    struct segment{

        struct page
        {
            int pid;
            int p[4];
        }pages[n];
    }segments[n];
}processes[3];


int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    int k = 0;
     for(a = 0; a < 3; a++)
     {
        for(b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {
            for(c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                k++;
                processes[a].segments[b].pages[c].pid = k;
                printf("Segment: %d, Page: %d, PID: %d\n",a,b,processes[a].segments[b].pages[c].pid);
            }
        }

     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel and Mah for your help. I fixed the code. And Thanks Stephen for the input. I will change my naming convention when I #define next time.

Comment: @Key you seem to have gone back and forth deciding which answer to accept. It would be nice to at least up vote whichever you're not accepting since you can only accept one. Glad you got the help you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `segments` element is shown as only being a single structure. Your diagram (and the way you seem to intend to use it) suggests it should be an array of them, like:

```
struct process
{
    struct segment{

        struct page
        {
            int pid;
            int p[4];
        }pages;
    }segments[4];   // <-------- [4]
};
```

You're also declaring:

```
struct page pages[n];
struct segment segments[n];
```

which you never actually use… you (rightfully, I think) use their kin inside your process structure. (This also means you're ignoring the #define n, effectively)